Issues with loading fallback images in Elementor
I've written some custom functions that pull in entries to a custom post type WordPress as checkbox choices in a field in Advanced Custom Fields.  However, something in this code is preventing the fallback images in an Elementor hero area from loading.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
/***************************
 * Populate Points of Interest Options in Outdoor Rec Checkboxes
***************************/

function populate_outdoor_rec_poi_select_field( $field ) {

    $rec_poi_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'point-of-interest',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all points of interest
        )
    );
    $options = array();

    if ( $rec_poi_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $rec_poi_query->have_posts() ) {
            $rec_poi_query->the_post();
            if(get_field('poi_map_link')) {
                $options[get_field('poi_map_link')] = get_the_title();
            }
        }
    }
    $field['choices'] = $options;

    return $field;

}
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=outdoor_rec_points_of_interest', 'populate_outdoor_rec_poi_select_field' );

